# Angular custom elements and semantic tags

Tags: angular

I try decompose my components into small pieces and faced with semantic and class managment problems.

For example: nested structure with three components: publication, publication-header and publication-title.

PublicationComponent:

```
<article class="publication">
  <app-publication-header></app-publication-header>
</article>
```

PublicationHeaderComponent:

```
<header class="publication__header">
  <app-publication-title></app-publication-title>
</header>
```

PublicationTitleComponent:

```
<h1 class="publication__title">Publication Title</h1>
```

---

Resulting code looks verbose.

1. Do i need wrapper tags or only custom elements?
2. Where to place classes: on custom elements or wrapper tags?
3. Do use classes or encapsulation?
4. If not classes, how to manage styles in nested components depending on parent property binding? (for example, bind publication `theme` property and properly change publication-title styles)

### Which code do I prefe?

Resulting code variants:

```
<app-publication>
  <article class="publication">

    <app-publication-header>
      <header class="publication__header">

        <app-publication-title>
          <h1 class="publication__title">Publication Title</h1>
        </app-publication-title>

      </header>
    </app-publication-header>

  </article>
</app-publication>
```

---

```
<app-publication class="publication">
  <article>

    <app-publication-header class="publication__header">
      <header>

        <app-publication-title class="publication__title">
          <h1>Publication Title</h1>
        </app-publication-title>

      </header>
    </app-publication-header>

  </article>
</app-publication>
```

---

```
<app-publication class="publication">
  <app-publication-header class="publication__header">
    <app-publication-title class="publication__title">Publication Title</app-publication-title>
  </app-publication-header>
</app-publication>
```

---

```
<app-publication>
  <app-publication-header>
    <app-publication-title>Publication Title</app-publication-title>
  </app-publication-header>
</app-publication>
```

Answer (score 1):

edited to top-link a solution - see https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/when-to-use-an-attribute-selector-for-angular-components-7e788ba1bfe7

While I completely understand Kuldeeps suggestions and agree many of them I disagree with his final outcome.
I also have the problem you seem to have.
I want to write good clean html5 with good semantic markup, and no extra tags.
Your code should be able to generate...

```
<article class="publication">
  <header>
    <h1>Publication Title</h1>
  </header>
</article>
```

(although your use of header is - I think - incorrect - it's for the page, not an article - but I'm not an expert)
I'm not aware of any way in angular to do this - I found your question while searching for an answer to the same.
I wonder if using an attribute mapping for the component might allow it, so you could use...

```
<article app-publication>
```

and

```
<header app-publication-header>
```

and have them picked up as components as if you'd used

```
<app-publication>
```

and

```
<app-publication-header>
```

It looks like this is done by setting your selector to be attribute based.
So instead of

```
selector: "app-publication",
```

which looks for

```
<app-publication>
```

you use

```
selector: "[app-publication]",
```

which looks for

```
<{anytag} app-publication>
```

I'm about to go try to see if you can do

```
selector: "article [app-publication]",
```

to limit it to only applying on articles.

Please reply if you found any better solutions - you are trying to use html5 correctly so don't be put off if angular limits you.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend you to write your code in such a way that it is very readable and manintainable

You have to make sure you don't pollute your `html`.

You should always components based structure to make your code loosely coupled. So as to reuse it if necessary.

All the classes and styling should be private to `component`.

For using nested styling, use `decorator` pattern, so that the `component` remains configurable.

I would suggest you to use code like below,

```html
<app-publication>
  <app-publication-header>
    <app-publication-title>Publication Title</app-publication-title>
  </app-publication-header>
</app-publication>
```